# converting timeslots from string to time using datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime, strptime

I need to plot campaign data using matplotlib. The time sent out needs to be compared between different camapigns running on the same day, so only the `HH:MM` is important, and that's provided  in a separate column.
I receive the data in csv, with one column showing the times, unfortunately if it was sent out at eg `09:45`, it apperars as `9:45`:

```
['9:05', '9:20', '9:25', '9:35', '9:40', '10:17', '10:22'...]
```

Can anyone please give me hint? I use Python 3, really beginer user, so believe soemone could point out my obvious mistake and direct me to the right solution. Thanks

```
import pandas
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time

file_name = r'''C:\\Users\\testing.csv''' # name of your excel file
df1 = pandas.read_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8')

df_Campaign1 = df1[df1['DataSource ID'].str.contains('Campaign1')==True]
Campaign1_times = df_Campaign1['time sent'].tolist()

Campaign1_times = [datetime.strptime(slot,"%H:%M") for slot in Campaign1_times]

print(Campaign1_times)
```

I expected to receive `09:05` etc datetime format so I can plot multiple campaigns results against each other on a timeline but unfortunately the output is:

```
[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 5), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 20), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 25), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 35), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 40), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 17)...]
```

Comment: Times without dates are pretty much meaningless. You get the default date added; if you don't have actual datetimes then this should be no problem at all

Comment: What is the difference between 22:00 and 07:00? The leading zero is not the issue, it's the date context.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that, so if I would like it to display HH:MM and I can'/dont need to provide the date, shall I use a different function? I need to plot various camapign data against each other so I need to keep them all in a timeline - the point is to check which one performs better in a given time (range of time).

Comment: If it's only a question of time, and they all occur on the same day, then you can live with `1900` as the year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thi is probably far from the best solution, but the following code returned the time in a HH:MM:SS format. Is this what you need?

```
import datetime
time_ = str(datetime.datetime.strptime('9:30', '%H:%M').time())
print(time_)
```

The example returns the following string: '09:30:00'

Comment: thanks a lot, this unfortunately returns a str, datetime.strptime(slot, '%H:%M').strftime('%H:%M') would do the same returning 09:05, however, I need to have the format as datetime/time, otherwise I can't plot multiple campaigns on the same timeline - that's a different issue, but seems to me that if I do it using str, matplotlib starts to plot one after the other rather than displaying them on the same timeline.

Comment: Just remove the str conversion and it returns a datetime.time object.
time_ =  datetime.datetime.strptime('9:30', '%H:%M').time()
print(type(time_))
<class 'datetime.time'>

Comment: thanks, it actually did the job - and sorry, it's 9pm and I've been working on this since the morning(